# Webmatrix cannot connect to azure database and fails to publish website as a result

Tags: azure, drupal-7, webmatrix

I have created a Drupal7 website in Webmatrix 3 and it all works fine. I followed the instructions [here](http://devproconnections.com/windows-azure-development/develop-and-deploy-web-apps-windows-azure-microsoft-webmatrix-2) to pre-provision a website and database on Azure, download a publish profile and attempt to use it to deploy the website. I imported the profile but no database connection setting appeared in the settings dialog, so I entered the relevant details and attempted to validate. The connection settings I put in are like this:

Server:     asdfghjk.database.windows.net
Database:   abcdrupal7
User:       abc
Password:   V1earb13H

When I validate Webmatrix says it can connect to the server but not the database. I have also tried the user id in the form abc@asdfghjk with no greater success. I can log in to the database server on azure using these details.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: p.s. I have my IP address listed in allowed IP addresses for the azure database

Comment: p.p.s I also have allow Azure services set to Yes.